# Contact form data field will not clear after submission

Tags: php

I am having problem with this contact form. The input fields do not clear after the form is submitted. The contact form works fine, sends message, validates data, and prints a success message.

Can some one suggest a way to clear the data fields after form submission?

I have try setting the fields value to null after submission and different reset functions without success.

What needs to happen for the data fields to clear?

[image: form screen capture]
[form url](http://photoshopace.com/transfer/contact-form-trial/form5-v1.4.0/trial.html)

Comment: Please post some code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
$('#contact-form').find('form')[0].reset();
```

to your success handler?

Answer (score 0):

> After submit the form, redirect the page

```
header("Location: success.html");
exit; // Location header is set, pointless to send HTML, stop the script
```

> If you are using jquery means, please try this

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this after success..
if it doesnt work try to add on send click function and check ..

$("#field1").val("");

$("#field2").val("");

$("#field3").val("");

Answer (score 0):

It's typically a good practice to use **POST-REDIRECT-GET** pattern for form handling. After the submitted form is already handled successfully, you should do a redirect: either another page or reload current page. It will reset the form data in your case. Another maybe-more-important benefit is it avoid the user from resubmitting the data by pressing reload button in the browser, which may cause unwanted duplicate request.

If you use this pattern, you must store your successful message across redirect. You can store it in session and clean it on next GET request.